# How to get the first word of a sentence in PHP?

Tags: php, string, extract, text-segmentation

I want to extract the first word of a variable from a string. For example, take this input:

```
<?php $myvalue = 'Test me more'; ?>
```

The resultant output should be `Test`, which is the first word of the input.
How can I do this?

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->words()[0]`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L363) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Comment: A small table of potential fringe cases when getting the substring before the first occurrence of a character: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68123370/2943403

Answer (score 293, accepted):

You can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function as follows:

```
$myvalue = 'Test me more';
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
echo $arr[0]; // will print Test
```

Another example:

```
$sentence = 'Hello World this is PHP';
$abbreviation = explode(' ', trim($sentence ))[0];
echo $abbreviation // will print Hello
```

Comment: Using modern PHP syntax you can just do `explode(' ',trim($myvalue))[0]`

Comment: 1 line code for any PHP version : `list($firstword) = explode(' ', trim($myvalue), 1);`

Comment: @CédricFrançoys the `limit` parameter should be 2 since it has to include the last element that contains the rest of the string; 1 would just return the very same string. Unless a big array would be created I would go with Elliot version for a one liner.

Comment: What if you want the second word as well as from RSS [NewYorkTimes](http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Sports.xml) - media:credit is - <media:credit>Dmitry Kostyukov for The New York Times</media:credit> . I only want Dmitry Kostyukov - How do I do that? =)

Comment: @xxxx, do `explode(" ",strip_tags("<media:credit>Dmitry Kostyukov for The New York Times</media:credit>"))[0]`

Comment: @j4k3 Please remember to [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: If you're looking for the most inefficient way to get the first word in a string, this is a good solution. In all other cases you're better off with literally every other answer here. How does this get any upvotes?

Comment: This is not the best answer! It echoes "one," if the string is "one, two three". The best answer is lower down, @Ciul

Comment: Doesn't work.  try this with this string: "\n\nNextWord".  This answer assumes all words are separate by spaces only.

Comment: Words do not end at the first space, but at the first character, that's not a letter. For eample `"Hey, how are you?` (returns "Hey,") or `Stop! Now` (returns "Stop!)

Answer (score 332):

There is a string function ([strtok](http://php.net/strtok)) which can be used to split a string into smaller strings (*tokens*) based on some separator(s).  For the purposes of this thread, the first word (defined as anything before the first space character) of `Test me more` can be obtained by *tokenizing* the string on the space character.

```
<?php
$value = "Test me more";
echo strtok($value, " "); // Test
?>
```

For more details and examples, see the [strtok PHP manual page](http://php.net/strtok).

Comment: This should be the first answer. It only returns the first word like he wanted in a cleaner way.

Comment: Good solution but in the php manual, it warns: This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.

Comment: I'm using PHP on a daily basis for at least 6 years and I didn't ever heard about this function until now

Comment: `strtok` is a weird and dangerous function that holds a global state. Using this function should be discouraged.

Comment: Doesn't work.  try this with this string: "\n\nNextWord".  This answer assumes all words are separate by spaces only.

Answer (score 45):

If you have PHP 5.3

```
$myvalue = 'Test me more';
echo strstr($myvalue, ' ', true);
```

note that if `$myvalue` is a string with one word `strstr` doesn't return anything in this case. A solution could be to append a space to the test-string:

```
echo strstr( $myvalue . ' ', ' ', true );
```

That will always return the first word of the string, even if the string has just one word in it

The alternative is something like:

```
$i = strpos($myvalue, ' ');
echo $i !== false ? $myvalue : substr( $myvalue, 0, $i );
```

Or using explode, which has so many answers using it I won't bother pointing out how to do it.

Comment: +1 for not using explode or regex (both inappropriate imho). Another alternative would be to use strstr with str_replace, replacing the part after the needle from strstr with nothing.

Comment: Worth noting, that although `strstr` is available in PHP since `4.3.0` it was not before `5.3.0`, when the optional parameter `before_needle` (which you're using in this example) was added. Just a notice, because I was confused, why you state, that this example needs `5.3.0`.

Comment: Note that if you set myvalue to a single word strstr doesn't return anything in this case! A solution could be to always add a space at the end of the string that's tested so it always comes back with the first word, even if that's the only word in the string!

Comment: Assuming only spaces between words is risky, I'd also include tabs.

Comment: shouldn't that be `echo $i === false ? $myvalue : substr( $myvalue, 0, $i );`

Comment: Doesn't work.  try this with this string: "\n\nNextWord".  This answer assumes all words are separate by spaces only.

Answer (score 24):

You could do

```
echo current(explode(' ',$myvalue));
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  try this with this string: "\n\nNextWord".  This answer assumes all words are separate by spaces only.

Comment: The original question's sample data does not contain any leading newline characters.

Answer (score 15):

Even though it is little late, but PHP has one better solution for this:

```
$words=str_word_count($myvalue, 1);
echo $words[0];
```

Answer (score 7):

Similar to accepted answer with one less step:

```
$my_value = 'Test me more';
$first_word = explode(' ',trim($my_value))[0];

//$first_word == 'Test'
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  try this with this string: "\n\nNextWord".  This answer assumes all words are separate by spaces only.

Comment: yes, this does assume a "sentence" is constructed of words separated by spaces

Comment: I think you missed the point.  I upper-cased "W" in word so you could read it easier.  Maybe this will make more sense to you - "\n\nThis won't work".  The above code will think the first word is "\n\nThis"

Comment: This late, redundant, unexplained answer missed a great opportunity to limit the number of explosions.

Comment: This is the first time in my life I've ever wanted less explosions.

Comment: lol, thanks for the comment @mickmackusa

Answer (score 5):

Just in case you are not sure the string starts with a word...

```
$input = ' Test me more ';
echo preg_replace('/(\s*)([^\s]*)(.*)/', '$2', $input); //Test
```

Comment: `trim($input)` would suffice in this instance :P

Comment: I would not capture the `\s*`.  I would not write `[^\s]` because `\S` is simpler.  I would not capture the `.*` at the end.  This answer is doing too many unnecessary things for a such a small snippet.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
  $value = "Hello world";
  $tokens = explode(" ", $value);
  echo $tokens[0];
?>
```

Just use explode to get every word of the input and output the first element of the resulting array.

Comment: Doesn't work.  try this with this string: "\n\nNextWord".  This answer assumes all words are separate by spaces only.

Comment: This answer does not limit the number of explosions, so it is potentially doing more work than what is required.

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = ' Test me more ';
preg_match('/\b\w+\b/i', $string, $result); // Test
echo $result;

/* You could use [a-zA-Z]+ instead of \w+ if wanted only alphabetical chars. */
$string = ' Test me more ';
preg_match('/\b[a-zA-Z]+\b/i', $string, $result); // Test
echo $result;
```

Regards,
Ciul

Comment: This would be the best answer, since it also works for "one, two and three" (the accepted answer would echo "one,")

Comment: Why use `i` pattern modifier if the character class has `[a-zA-Z]` or if you are using `\w`?  What should the output be if the first "word" contains an apostrophe or hyphen? Food for thought.  This unexplained answer is teaching  unnecessary things.

Answer (score 3):

Using split function also you can get the first word from string.

```
<?php
$myvalue ="Test me more";
$result=split(" ",$myvalue);
echo $result[0];
?>
```

Comment: NOTE- split() is DEPRECATED from 5.3 >

Comment: There is no limit to the `split()`, so this technique will be over-functioning.  It only needs to explode on the first occurring space to do the job properly.

Answer (score 3):

personally `strsplit` / `explode` / `strtok` does not support word boundaries, so to get a more accute split use regular expression with the `\w`

```
preg_split('/[\s]+/',$string,1);
```

This would split words with boundaries to a limit of 1.

Comment: RobertPitt -> It would be helpful if you gave an example where strtok failed with a word boundary as compared to a preg_split.

Comment: There is no reason to wrap `\s` in a character class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know how fast each of these respective functions is, I ran some crude benchmarking in PHP 7.3 on the six most voted answers here (`strpos` with `substr`, `explode` with `current`, `strstr`, `explode` with `trim`, `str_word_count` and `strtok`) with 1,000,000 iterations each to compare their speeds.

```
<?php

$strTest = 'This is a string to test fetching first word of a string methods.';

$before = microtime(true);
for ($i=0 ; $i<1000000 ; $i++) {
    $p = strpos($strTest, ' ');
    $p !== false ? $strTest : substr( $strTest, 0, $p );
}
$after = microtime(true);
echo 'strpos/ substr: '.($after-$before)/$i . ' seconds<br>';

$before = microtime(true);
for ($i=0 ; $i<1000000 ; $i++) {
    strstr($strTest, ' ', true);
}
$after = microtime(true);
echo 'strstr: '.($after-$before)/$i . ' seconds<br>';

$before = microtime(true);
for ($i=0 ; $i<1000000 ; $i++) {
    current(explode(' ',$strTest));
}
$after = microtime(true);
echo 'explode/ current: '.($after-$before)/$i . ' seconds<br>';

$before = microtime(true);
for ($i=0 ; $i<1000000 ; $i++) {
    $arr = explode(' ',trim($strTest));
    $arr[0];
}
$after = microtime(true);
echo 'explode/ trim: '.($after-$before)/$i . ' seconds<br>';

$before = microtime(true);
for ($i=0 ; $i<1000000 ; $i++) {
    str_word_count($strTest, 1);
}
$after = microtime(true);
echo 'str_word_count: '.($after-$before)/$i . ' seconds<br>';

$before = microtime(true);
for ($i=0 ; $i<1000000 ; $i++) {
    strtok($value, ' ');
}
$after = microtime(true);
echo 'strtok: '.($after-$before)/$i . ' seconds<br>';

?>
```

Here are the varying results from 2 consecutive runs:

```
strpos/ substr: 6.0736894607544E-8 seconds
strstr: 5.0434112548828E-8 seconds
explode/ current: 3.5163116455078E-7 seconds
explode/ trim: 3.8683795928955E-7 seconds
str_word_count: 4.6665270328522E-6 seconds
strtok: 4.9849510192871E-7 seconds

strpos/ substr: 5.7171106338501E-8 seconds
strstr: 4.7624826431274E-8 seconds
explode/ current: 3.3753299713135E-7 seconds
explode/ trim: 4.2293286323547E-7 seconds
str_word_count: 3.7025549411774E-6 seconds
strtok: 1.2249300479889E-6 seconds
```

And the results after inverting the order of the functions:

```
strtok: 4.2612719535828E-7 seconds
str_word_count: 4.1899878978729E-6 seconds
explode/ trim: 9.3175292015076E-7 seconds
explode/ current: 7.0811605453491E-7 seconds
strstr: 1.0137891769409E-7 seconds
strpos/ substr: 1.0082197189331E-7 seconds
```

**Conclusion** It turns out that the speed between these functions varies widely and is not as consistent between test runs as you might expect. According to these quick and dirty tests, any of the six chosen functions will get the job done in a reasonable amount of time. There are perturbations including other processes running that are interfering with the execution times. So just use whatever function makes the most practical and readable sense to you as a programmer. For the bigger programming picture, see [Donald Knuth's *Literate Programming*](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/lp.html).

Comment: I would be happier if I saw `explode()` benchmarks that properly use the limit argument of `2`, so that no unnecessary exploding is done.

Comment: Also, if trimming is going to be done, it is logical to only `ltrim()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$input = "Test me more";
echo preg_replace("/\s.*$/","",$input); // "Test"
```

Comment: The `$` end of string metacharacter is not necessary for this pattern to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

[`strtok`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) is quicker than `extract` or [`preg_*`](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) functions.

Comment: This answer seems more like a comment.  It seems to be trying to weigh-in on other answers.  I don't know how `extract()` is useful here.  `preg_` functions will be slower, but they offer more robust techniques that can weed out unwanted characters in fringe cases.

Answer (score 1):

You question could be reformulated as "replace in the string the first space and everything following by nothing" . So this can be achieved with a simple regular expression:

```
$firstWord = preg_replace("/\s.*/", '', ltrim($myvalue));
```

I have added an optional call to ltrim() to be safe: this function remove spaces at the begin of string.

Answer (score 0):

$first_word = str_word_count(1)[0]

Doesn't work on special characters, and will result in wrong behaviour if special characters are used. It is not UTF-8 friendly.

For more info check [is PHP str_word_count() multibyte safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290537/is-php-str-word-count-multibyte-safe)

Answer (score -2):

If there is punctuation involved, then use `preg_split()`...

```
$string=" However, Lorem ipsum";
echo "[".preg_split('/[, ();.]/', trim($string))[0]."]";
```

See https://onlinephp.io/c/25087

Comment: Why is comma nominated twice in the character class?  Why use `trim()` when you can explicitly tell `preg_split()` to omit empty elements? If you only want the first element, then you should limit the number of splits so that the the function doesn't do unnecessary work.  I would never use `preg_split()` for this task -- it is indirect programming to create an array from a string, then access the array to return a string.