# Get first word of every line

Tags: php

I need to get every first word of the lines in my `$lines`. So I'm doing an `foreach` on every line like this:

```
foreach ($lines as $n => $line) {

}
```

But then the next part, I need to grab only the first word. So I did this with exploding on a space like this:

```
$explode = explode(" ", $line);
echo $explode[0];
```

But this is very slow when I do it with many lines, is there a better and faster solution then using an `explode()` ?

Comment: how about telling us an example of that $line?

Comment: You could iterate over each line until you find a space. This will be your word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes!

`$var = substr( $line, 0, strpos( $line, ' ' ) );`

`substr()` trims a string using start position (0, the beginning) and length: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

We determine the length by using `strpos()` to find the first occurrence of the search phrase (in this case, a space): http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: How is this any faster than using `explode`?

Comment: It's faster because it stops at the first space instead of finding every space like explode().

Comment: Thanks @SetSailMedia, it works and my loading time was way better! Will accept your answer within a few minutes :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).  Get the index of the first space with strpos and then use that index as the end of your substr.  That will save you exploding each line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the String Token function
 http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtok.asp

Comment: How is this any better than exploding on a space?

Comment: @tborychowski huh, didnt know that. Found the site via google and some examples where helpful to me in the past.

Comment: @JulianSchaefer That's a common trap: to trust google. It's like going to school for education :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex. This should get the match before first space. `(?:^|(?:\.\s))(\w+)`

Comment: I don't believe that will be any faster than explode.  Or will it?

Comment: @UFL1138 Its faster because regular expressions, if used correctly, stop as soon as they have the first match and don't operate on the entire string in compare to explode.

Comment: Still there's a lot of overhead to instantiate the regex engine.  At any rate it will certainly not be faster than using strpos and substr.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
list($firstWord) = explode(" ",trim($line));
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476789/how-to-get-the-first-word-of-a-sentence-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with the limit:

```
explode(" ", $line, 1);
```

Although this is much faster than `explode` without the limit, it is not as fast as the `substr()` solution suggested by the user: `Set Sail Media`.

In my tests with 100K lines, every line having around 10K words:

```
explode       : 175s
explode+limit : 0s
substr()      : 0s
```

With 1M lines, every line having around 20K words:

```
explode       : too long :-)
explode+limit : 12s
substr()      : 0s
```

Comment: How about 1M lines each with only about 20 words?