# showing only first letter or paragraph

Tags: php, codeigniter

can anyone helping me to showing first name/word on navigation? i've trying this code

`<div class="d-sm-none d-lg-inline-block">Welcome, <?php $string = $this->session->userdata('name'); echo $firstCharacter = $string[0]; ?></div></a>`

but this code only showing the first character. i mean like if my name george bush then it only get "Welcome, g". i want to showing more like "Welcome, george" without bush. how to do it?

sorry for my bad english and i'm new to php things. and thanks for helping me before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the first word of a sentence in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476789/how-to-get-the-first-word-of-a-sentence-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions, like this:

`echo preg_replace('/^([^\s]+)\s*.*$/', '$1', $string);`

or split it:

`echo (explode(' ', $string))[0]`;

or 'tok' it:

`echo strtok($string, " ")`

Answer (score 0):

To get the 1st word, please use explode to separate the words by space into array, then get the 1st element of the array

Please use this:

```
<?php 

$string = $this->session->userdata('name'); 
$arr = explode(' ',trim($string));
echo $arr[0]; 

?>
```

So for your case

```
<div class="d-sm-none d-lg-inline-block"> Welcome, 
<?php $string = $this->session->userdata('name'); 
$arr = explode(' ',trim($string));echo $arr[0];  ?> </div></a>
```