# Remove all characters after a specific character

Tags: php, substring, truncate

Can anyone tell me how to remove characters after `?` in php. I have a string `test?q=new` and I need to remove the characters from the `?` to the end of the string.

Comment: Where do you see this?  `test?=new`

Comment: sorry slight difference test?q=new

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Shortest one:

```
echo strtok('test?=new', '?');
```

If you want to keep the question mark, the solution is almost the same:

```
echo strtok('test?=new', '?').'?';
```

Comment: This is stripping the question mark. OP says all characters after the `?`

Answer (score 5):

You could always try using `preg_replace()` as well:

```
$string = 'test?q=new';
$result = preg_replace("/\?.+/", "", $string);
```

If, for some reason, you are wanting to keep the `?` in the result... you could also do this:

```
$string = 'test?q=new';
$result = preg_replace("/\?.+/", "?", $string);
```

(or, you could use a positive look-behind assertion, as @BlueJ774 suggested,) like this:

```
$result = preg_replace("/(?<=\?).+/", "", $string);
```

But ideally, *and for future reference*, if you are working with a *query string*, you probably will want to use [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) *at some point*, like this:

```
$string = 'test?q=new';
parse_str($string, $output);
```

Because that will give you an array (`$output`, in this case,) with which to work with all of the parts of the query string, like this:

```
Array
(
    [test?q] => new
)
```

But normally... you would probably just want to be working with the query string by this point... so the output would be more like this:

```
Array
(
    [q] => new
)
```

Comment: The second `preg_replace` (where the `?` is kept) could also be represented as `$result = preg_replace("/(?<=\?).+/", "", $string);`  I think the intent is clearer that way.

Comment: Good point.  In a regular script, that would make more sense; it's just for the sake of this example, I kept both of the expressions the same for simplicity.  But I would imagine the `?` would normally not be saved...

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
$pos = strpos($str, '?'); // ? position
$str = substr($str, 0, $pos);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a well-written regex, but the much simpler and quicker way to do it is to explode the string on the "?" character, and use the first element in the resulting array.

```
$str = "test?=new";
$str2 = explode("?", $str);
$use_this = $str2[0];
```

$use_this[0] will be "test".  If you want to add the "?" back, just concatenate:

```
$use_this = $use_this."?";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one-liner:

```
$s = strpos($s, '?') !== FALSE ? strtok($s, '?') : $s;
```

You can test it by the following command-line:

```
php -r '$s = "123?456"; $s = strpos($s, "?") !== FALSE ? strtok($s, "?") : $s; echo $s;'
```

Answer (score 0):

### `substr` and `strpos`

The simplest way to do this is with [`substr()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/strpos).

```
$string = 'test?=new';
$cut_position = strpos($string, '?') + 1; // remove the +1 if you don't want the ? included
$string = substr($string, 0, $cut_position);
```

As you can see `substr()` extracts a sub-string from a string by index and `strpos()` returns the index of the first instance of the character it is searching for (in this case `?`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function.

```
<?php
$myString = "test?=new";
$result = strstr($myString, '=', true);

echo $result ;
```

The third parameter `true` tells the function to return everything before the first occurrence of the second parameter.