# Remove optional time component from datetime stamp string

Tags: php, timestamp, date-format, substr, strip

I am processing some strings in a PHP script which may be in `Y-m-d H:i:s` or `Y-m-d` format.  I need to remove the  `H:i:s` portion from the datetime strings so that I am consistently dealing with `Y-m-d` date strings.

How can I remove this trailing string (and its leading space) *if* it exists?

My strings might look like `2003-11-24 23:52:18` or `2009-01-25`.

My expected results from these strings are `2003-11-24` and `2009-01-25`.

I do not need to validate that these strings represent real "date" or "datetime" values.

Comment: Assuming the date is always padded. Why not do a substr on it?

Comment: Where are you getting this string? There may be an easier way.

Comment: Via whois results. It's to find domain age, and since every domain lists it differently, it can be tough. This is one format - most don't include timestamps like this.

Comment: We can only cover the cases you provide us. So if it has to be more flexible, tell us what should be covered.

Comment: `$new=trim(str_replace('00:00:00','',$date));`

Comment: @Dagon You didn't read the question. "No matter what numbers are in the 00:00:00"

Comment: @Bailey Without the space, there is ambiguity, unless you know the date is always going to be YYYY-MM-DD, with exactly two digits for the day. Otherwise, you don't know if   `2000-01-200:00:00` is the 2nd or 20th day of the month.

Comment: i did but that made no senses to me, why not say remove the time part of the date string, as the numbers in "00:00:00" are "00:00:00"

Comment: I think I've managed to find a way to fix the missing space.  Can someone make an answer that can detect it WITH a space and remove it, no matter what time it says? (while keeping in mind that it may not always be in the string).

Comment: He's just saying that's the format.  It could be "01:23:45" or "12:34:56"..... your solution is invalid.

Comment: not my problem if the op cant write a sensible question.

Comment: @Dagon I did state clearly: "No matter what numbers are in the 00:00:00 it should be stripped if exists", and that "the 00:00:00 may not always be in the string."

Comment: the numbers in the string "00:00:00"  are  "00:00:00" there can be no others, the cat in the box is a cat, not a dog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the length of the date is always fix. You can use `substr`.

```
// With 00:00:00
$date = '2003-01-2800:00:00';
echo substr($date, 0, 10) . '<br>';

// Without 00:00:00
$date = '2003-01-28';
echo substr($date, 0, 10) . '<br>'; 

// With other time part
$date = '2003-01-2812:00:11';
echo substr($date, 0, 10);
```

Comment: @Bailey This has no requirement of it being `00:00:00` - it's simply taking the first 10 characters. Will that work? Do you know the date will always be 10 chars?

Comment: I apologize, this is correct. I was interpreting it completely different, and I apparently did not read Jonathan's comment. Thanks. lol

Answer (score 1):

you could use a simple `explode` or as noted in the comments `substr` but if you don't know how the string will be formatted a more complex `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mytime))`  based on your updated post...

```
$newdate = substr($olddate,0,10);
```

Comment: @Bailey give us a real world example then ... "2003-01-2800:00:00" ?

Comment: Wait, there is no space in the incoming data? Or you want the space removed along with the time?

Comment: str_replace and trim another option

Comment: @Dagon what is `str_replace` going to do if you don't know the string you are replacing?

Answer (score 1):

Your incoming data is a date string, so treat it as such and use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) to manipulate it. Your solution could be as simple as:-

```
$dateString = (new \DateTime('2003-01-28 00:00:00'))->format('Y-m-d');
//$dateString now === '2003-01-28'
```

This will work even if the time portion (00:00:00) is missing. and even if there is no space between the date and time.

[As you can see](http://3v4l.org/PH08G) this should cover all of your possible inputs.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT #2 (using str_replace)

The position of `00:00:00` doesn't matter in this case, even if the dates have no space between them.

Works on `00:00:00 2003-01-28` and `2003-01-28 00:00:00` and `2003-01-2800:00:00`

```
<?php

$if_date_null = "00:00:00";
 
$replace = ""; // replace with nothing

// doesn't matter the position of 00:00:00
$dates = "00:00:00 2003-01-28";
// $dates = "2003-01-28 00:00:00";
 
$result = str_replace($if_date_null,$replace,$dates);
 
echo $result;

?>
```

---

### EDIT #1

```
<?php

$date = "2003-01-28";

$date_null = "00:00:00";

if (strpos($date_null,'00:00:00') !== false) {
    echo '00:00:00 found ';
}

else {

echo "No ZEROS found ";

}


?>
```

---

### Original answer

This will echo 2003-01-28 and not include the space between 2003-01-28 and 00:00:00

```
<?php

echo substr("2003-01-28 00:00:00",0,-9);

?>
```

You can also assign date as a variable like this: (will produce the same result) and use that variable elsewhere if needed.

```
<?php

$date = "2003-01-28";
echo substr("$date 00:00:00",0,-9);

?>
```

Comment: But what if "00:00:00" isn't in the string? Then the date gets cut off. As stated, it won't always be in there.

Comment: @Bailey I was under the impression that `00:00:00` was the last string.

Comment: Sometimes. It varies depending on the domain name entered. That's why this is so hard - it must first be detected before removed.

Comment: @Bailey Ok, so it's an "if exist" then. That's going to need an `if` condition then. The code will need to be a bit heftier.

Comment: @Bailey Yet, it shouldn't matter, since if your left date is the one you need, and the one to the right is unknown, as long as there are 8 digits plus the space, you're still going to end up with the string that you need on the left, correct?

Comment: @Bailey Have a look at my updated answer, see if that will work for you.

Comment: Hi, I meant that the 00:00:00 can change too. >.>

Comment: @Bailey *"No matter what numbers are in the 00:00:00 it should be stripped if exists."* if "what" exists, that's what baffles me.

Comment: @Bailey *"Additionally, the 00:00:00 may not always be in the string. That's why I need to detect it first."* and that's what my script does. Try it and see, then change `$date_null = "00:00:00";` to `$date_null = "00:00:01";` and you will see the result.

Comment: The 00:00:00 is a timestamp, meaning it can change depending on the time. :) I selected the answer above, though it isn't ideal. The date can be any part of the string (maybe "00:00:00 2013-08-04") and the solution I chose only works for the opposite of that, but oh well. :)

Comment: @Bailey First your question is *"to remove the 00:00:00 from "2003-01-28 00:00:00"* and now you are saying it's the opposite. It won't matter. If my script detects `00:00:00` to the left or right, it will strip it.

Comment: @Bailey Just thought you'd like to know, I made another edit using `str_replace` (see details inside). You're welcome to use it, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use function "date()" to format the timestamp

```
<?php
$my_date = "2003-01-28 00:00:00";
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", time($my_date));
var_dump($new_date);
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: time() expects exactly 0 arguments`

Answer (score 0):

First things first, if you are receiving this input data from an earlier layer that is in your control (such as a sql result set), then you should probably standardize the string format before your php touches it.  If this data is born from some kind of sql like `COALESCE(my_datetime, my_date) AS datetime_or_date`, then you could spare your php having to perform potentially iterated calls on each row of your result set.  Within your coalescing process, it will be simple to leverage some functions such as `CAST()`, `DATE()`, `DATE_FORMAT()`, `CONVERT()`, or `STR_TO_DATE()` depending on the scenario.

Now, this task seems to have a fairly narrow scope.  The input data is either `Y-m-d H:i:s` or `Y-m-d`.  This is not about validation -- only text extraction.  In this case, there are several php techniques that can be trusted (and some that can't be).  For researchers that may not have valid date/datetime values or the values might be an empty strings or even `null`, you should be careful about possible side effects of the function/technique that you use.

Consider the following tables of test strings and techniques, and choose with care: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XrNPi))

|  | "2003-01-28 01:23:45" (valid datetime) | "2007-04-04" (valid date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `substr($datetime, 0, 10)` | "2003-01-28" | "2007-04-04" |
| `explode(' ', $datetime, 2)[0]` | "2003-01-28" | "2007-04-04" |
| `sscanf($datetime, '%s', $sscanf); $sscanf` | "2003-01-28" | "2007-04-04" |
| `preg_replace('/ .+/', '', $datetime)` | "2003-01-28" | "2007-04-04" |
| `(new \DateTime($datetime))->format('Y-m-d')` | "2003-01-28" | "2007-04-04" |
| `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datetime))` | "2003-01-28" | "2007-04-04" |
| `strtok($datetime, ' ')` | "2003-01-28" | "2007-04-04" |
| `strstr($datetime . ' ', ' ', true)` | "2003-01-28" | "2003-04-04" |

|  | "0000-00-00 00:00:00" (invalid datetime) | "0000-00-00" (invalid date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `substr($datetime, 0, 10)` | "0000-00-00" | "0000-00-00" |
| `explode(' ', $datetime, 2)[0]` | "0000-00-00" | "0000-00-00" |
| `sscanf($datetime, '%s', $sscanf); $sscanf` | "0000-00-00" | "0000-00-00" |
| `preg_replace('/ .+/', '', $datetime)` | "0000-00-00" | "0000-00-00" |
| `(new \DateTime($datetime))->format('Y-m-d')` | "-0001-11-30" | "-0001-11-30" |
| `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datetime))` | "-0001-11-30" | "-0001-11-30" |
| `strtok($datetime, ' ')` | "0000-00-00" | "0000-00-00" |
| `strstr($datetime . ' ', ' ', true)` | "0000-00-00" | "0000-00-00" |

|  | "" (empty string) | null (null value) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `substr($datetime, 0, 10)` | "" | "" |
| `explode(' ', $datetime, 2)[0]` | "" | "" |
| `sscanf($datetime, '%s', $sscanf); $sscanf` | null | null |
| `preg_replace('/ .+/', '', $datetime)` | "" | "" |
| `(new \DateTime($datetime))->format('Y-m-d')` | "2021-08-21" (current date) | "2021-08-21" (current date) |
| `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datetime))` | "1970-01-01" | "1970-01-01" |
| `strtok($datetime, ' ')` | false | false |
| `strstr($datetime . ' ', ' ', true)` | "" | "" |

Some explicit notes:

1. `substr()` is a fine tool for this job and returns a stable value in the above cases.
2. `explode()` is stable, but not direct since it needs to create an array in the process.
3. `sscanf()` with `%s` searches for the leading substring until a whitespace character is encountered.  This is direct, but some might argue that it is lesser known and unintuitive. Also, it provides a reference variable that may need to be `unset()` in some situations. This exact technique is ONLY useful for this specific scenario.  Depending on how the input string and the delimiter may vary, `sscanf()` may or may not be viable.
4. `preg_replace()` provides a stable result, but it will never win on speed.  Frankly, there is no benefit to wheeling out the regex engine when there are non-regex techniques that can do the exact same thing.  Not recommended.
5. `format()` can provide some unwanted results when an invalid or missing value is provided. I would argue that because this is merely a text-extraction task, there is no need to instantiate a datetime object and call a formatting method. Not recommended.
6. `strtotime()` & `date()` can provide some unwanted results when an invalid or missing value is provided. I don't see any reason to call two functions when the task can be done in one function call. Not recommended.
7. `strtok()` might be the most ideal and is the most concise technique when values are guaranteed to have length.  However, when the input has no length, be aware of the boolean return value.
8. `strstr()` can be used for this task, but to ensure a stable return value, the delimiting character must be unconditionally appended to the string being searched.  In other words, the delimiter must be found. This technique just feels unnecessarily hacky, given that other techniques don't need to mutate the input string.