# Image src contain "&" symbol can not access this as url param

Tags: facebook, image, urlencode

I have an image src as :

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtl1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10291693_1478919849038582_6717876706471049180_n.jpg?oh=0e2416fd3373c0757b7f3dd40169dfa9&oe=57127C81

it contains symbol '&' i need to use url without '&' symbol.

I tried **urlencode** but it returns:

https%3A%2F%2Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-xtl1%2Fv%2Ft1.0-9%2Fs720x720%2F10291693_1478919849038582_6717876706471049180_n.jpg%3Foh%3D0e2416fd3373c0757b7f3dd40169dfa9%26oe%3D57127C81

**Doesn't work.**

I also tried to replace '&' with '%26'

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtl1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10291693_1478919849038582_6717876706471049180_n.jpg?oh=0e2416fd3373c0757b7f3dd40169dfa9%26oe=57127C81

But no success. Any help?

Comment: _“i need to use url without '&' symbol”_ – why? In what context? How is the `&` a problem?

Comment: Because i have something like<a href="Some action?imgsrc=My_image_source"></a>

Comment: when i tried to access that imgsrc as $_REQUEST['imgsrc'] it exclude string after '&' symbol. i hope you got it.

Comment: So you want to pass that URL as a parameter value inside another URL? Then of course you need to URL-encode it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove everything after "&", for example:

```
$variable = substr($variable, 0, strpos($variable, '&'));
```

Source: [Remove portion of a string after a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588666/remove-portion-of-a-string-after-a-certain-character)