# How to replace GET parameters in URL

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

For example, if I have a URL http://example.com/?src=example&test_28934

How do I remove everything after ?, so the user always lands on http://example.com?

I have tried this and the URL stays the same.

```
$current_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_url = reset((explode('?', $current_url)));
```

Comment: Have a look at parse_url documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
and this [Remove portion of a string after a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588666/remove-portion-of-a-string-after-a-certain-character)

For your example it will be

```
$current_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_url = substr($current_url, 0, strpos($current_url, "?"));
```

Answer (score -1):

header("Location: " . "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "?");