# Remove everything after first commas (,) from string In Adobe LiveCycle

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, textfield, livecycle-designer

I have textfield1 and textfield2, I want to reduce characters after commas in textfield2

example:

textfield1 =

This is mango, the color is green

in textfield2 =

This is mango

I want to use if with initialization / trigger "comma (,)"

If in php like this :

[remove everything after first comma from string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131397/remove-everything-after-first-comma-from-string-in-php)

please help if anyone understands in adobe live cycle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this should do on an exit event.

```
var originalText      = textfield1.rawValue;
var placeOfFirstComma = originalText.indexOf(",");
var reducedText       = originalText.substring(0, placeOfFirstComma);
textfield2.rawValue   = reducedText;
```