# Remove all characters after the first comma in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

According to this post [remove everything after first comma from string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131397/remove-everything-after-first-comma-from-string-in-php)

I need customize this line in Wordpress:

```
<div class="text-center font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; text-decoration: underline;">
    <?php 
        echo rtrim( wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 2, '' ), ',' ); 
    ?>
</div>
```

It works good, but some product titles need to be longer than two words, so i need all words before comma character.

Comment: So what is wrong with the answer in the question you have linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it with [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
<div class="text-center font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; text-decoration: underline;">
    <?php 
        echo explode(',', get_the_title())[0]; 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @Juraj I am glad. Please consider accepting the answer, so it might help other people with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `preg_replace`

```
$f = "Hello there, im a post title, and some stuff";

echo preg_replace("/,.+/", "", $f); // Hello there
```

Comment: Thank you too, but regular expression is not unnecessary?

Comment: It might be more costly than ```explode``` in this case, but its applications are way broader. Regex is a powerful tool, and certainly one you should endeavor to learn.

Comment: An important part about learning any tool is when it's appropriate.  Regex are as you say very powerful and can do a lot, but in this example the need is so basic as for it to be not needed.

Comment: @Kyrre I agree with you, but NigelRen is right also. You should know when to use it. But knowing regex has proved useful countless of times. I have upvoted your answer, as it works and someone might find it useful for their particular use-case.